# An identity with the metric in general relativity, and index manipulation

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

In the context of general relativity, I want to prove that $$  g^{ij} = \frac{1}{g(n-1)!}\epsilon^{i \beta_2 \ldots \beta_n} \epsilon^{j \alpha_2 \ldots \alpha_n}g_{\beta_2\alpha_2}\ldots g_{\alpha_n\beta_n}  $$

where $g:=\det (g_{\mu\nu})$.

I start with
\begin{equation}
g = \epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}g_{1\alpha_1}\ldots g_{n\alpha_n} = \frac{1}{n!}\epsilon^{\beta_1\ldots\beta_n}\epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}g_{\beta_1\alpha_1}\ldots g_{\beta_n\alpha_n}
\end{equation}

So

\begin{align*} 
\partial_{\mu}g &=  \frac{1}{n!}\epsilon^{\beta_1\ldots\beta_n}\epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n} 
(\partial_\mu g_{\beta_1\alpha_1})\ldots g_{\beta_n\alpha_n} + \ldots + g_{\beta_1\alpha_1}\ldots (\partial_\mu g_{\beta_n\alpha_n}) \\ 
 &=  \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\epsilon^{\beta_1\ldots\beta_n}\epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}  (\partial_\mu g_{\beta_1\alpha_1})g_{\beta_2,\alpha_2}\ldots g_{\beta_n\alpha_n}
\end{align*}

Now

\begin{align*} 
g &= \epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}g_{1\alpha_1}\ldots g_{n\alpha_n} \\
  &= g_{1\alpha_1} \epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}g_{2\alpha_2}\ldots g_{n\alpha_n} \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}g_{1\alpha_1} \epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}\epsilon^{\beta_2\ldots\beta_n}g_{\beta_2\alpha_2}\ldots g_{\beta_2\alpha_n} \\
  \Rightarrow 1 &= \frac{1}{g(n-1)!}g_{1\alpha_1} \epsilon^{\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_n}\epsilon^{\beta_2\ldots\beta_n}g_{\beta_2\alpha_2}\ldots g_{\beta_2\alpha_n}
\end{align*}

now, I would like to somehow act with the inverse metric on both sides to get the result, but it doesn't really work: we have $1$ in the index of $g$ on the RHS, not some arbitrary index $i$. Also, the second levi-civita symbol onlt has $n-1$ idices, not $n$, as it was supposed to.

Comment: Are you sure that $g = \text{det}(g^{ij}) $ ? not $g = \text{det}(g_{ij}) $ ?

Comment: @Sou That is correct, I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to prove this. Note that for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ we have the identity

$$
\det(A) = \frac{1}{n!} \epsilon^{\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n} \epsilon^{\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_n} \prod_{i=1}^n A_{\alpha_i \beta_i}
$$
where we sum over repeated indices. Now suppose $A$ is invertible and let's write the components of $A^{-1}$ as $A^{ij}$ such that $A^{ij} A_{jk}= \delta^{i}_{k} = A_{kj} A^{ji}$. Now define the matrix $B$ with components
$$
B^{ij} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \epsilon^{i, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n} \epsilon^{j, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_n} \prod_{k=2}^n A_{\beta_k \alpha_k}
$$
It isn't too hard to see that the components of $B$ are precisely those of the adjugate of $A$, so $\text{adj}(A)=B$. Because $\text{adj}(A) \cdot A = A \cdot \text{adj(A)} = \det(A) I$, we find that

$$
A^{ij} = \frac{1}{\det(A)(n-1)!} \epsilon^{i, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n} \epsilon^{j, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_n} \prod_{k=2}^n A_{\beta_k \alpha_k}.
$$